# Nginx request giving ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING while try to connect

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have configured my nginx config file in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
filename:- subdomain.xyz

But When I am using proxy_pass in location directive it is giving me ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING in chrome browser.

My config file:-

```
    server {
         listen 443 ssl default_server;
         listen [::]:443 ssl default_server;
        server_name subdomain_name;
        include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://ip_address:port_number/services;
        }
    }
```

Can anyone help me on this.
Thankyou in advance

Comment: I have solved this quetion as I need to enable proxy_hadder in that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem using add proxy_hadder in nginx config file